# Use Jquery .change to sum a class of input boxes

Tags: jquery, class, input, sum, onchange

I'd like to make a `.change` event that fires whenever text is changed in a certain class of input boxes. I have several boxes that I would like to sum together and refresh the total any time the values are changed. Can I create a function that references a `.change` event for an entire class?

It's relatively straightforward to make a "change" action for an input box (id="Value1"):

```
$('#Value1').change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

So let's say that "Value1" is a class `SumText` box:

```
   <input class="SumText" type="text" id="Value1">
```

Every time that any of the fields of class "SumText" change I would like to fire a function that adds them all together. For  the sake of simplicity let's just say all we have is "Value1" and "Value2". We can output that sum to "Total". "Total" is of class `TotalText`

Can this be done in JQuery? It would save me from having to create an event handler for each, and from having to specify a target function in each input box for `onchange`.

Comment: Use `.keypress` to catch any changes in text input. But this will trigger each time keyboard button is pressed. `$('#Value1').keypress(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
`

Comment: Omar, that does seem to work quite well. I was unaware of that functionality (I'm still new to JQuery). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.SumText').change(function(){
    alert("Some text has been changed.");
});
```

There you have it. It is the same as for an ID, but with a dot instead of a pound sign.

**Edit:** But might be better served by the keypress or keydown methods instead, as has been pointed out by @omar